# I want execute button.click() operation once finds value more than "+1.00%" in a webpage using Selenium, python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Guy's please help, I want execute an element.click() operation once element finds an text in a web page  more than "+1.00%" value. Below is my code. The code will repeat until finds text more than "+1.00%"

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            element = browser.find_element_by_link_text('+1.00%')
            
            element2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Balances')
            if element > '+1.00%':
                element2.click()
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            main()
```

Comment: Add HTM, add your error, add. And do not use potentialy infinite loops or recursive functions.

Comment: please a bit clarification. I am new

Comment: Add the HTML code of the page where you are looking for the elements. Add the error if you have any of the errors, and add url of page.

Comment: you are getting element with +1.00 and +1.50 and validating they are equal? how will it be equal ?

Comment: I have corrected, to understand what I want

Comment: Overall I want to find element by text bigger than +1.00% value and execute element.click()

Comment: please add the html of the element , you should use some other locator than text to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium import webdriver

    driver.get('url')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"+1.50")]')
        )
    ).click()
```

use webdriver wait instead,

Comment: Will it search in a webpage value more than +1.00 ?

Comment: it will search for eleemnt that contain text +1.50

Comment: if you want anything more than 1 , then you have to use some other locator